# Make a method generic

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method that extract days names from a particular object, 
like this:

```
private string ExtractWeekDayNames(FiscalReceipt fiscalReceipt)
    {
        string retVal = "";

        Dictionary<string, bool> WeekDays = 
            new Dictionary<string, bool>() {
                                            { "Sun", fiscalReceipt.Sunday },
                                            { "Mon", fiscalReceipt.Monday },
                                            { "Tue", fiscalReceipt.Tuesday },
                                            { "Wed", fiscalReceipt.Wednesday },
                                            { "Thu", fiscalReceipt.Thursday },
                                            { "Fri", fiscalReceipt.Friday },
                                            { "Sat", fiscalReceipt.Saturday }
                                            };


        //Find week days
        foreach (var item in WeekDays)
        {
            if (item.Value == true)
                retVal += item.Key + ",";
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(retVal))
            retVal = retVal.Substring(0, retVal.Length - 1);

        return retVal;

    }
```

I also have a similar method that performs the same operations 
but having a different type of parameter, like:

```
private string ExtractWeekDayNames(NonFiscalReceipt nonFiscalReceipt)
{
    ...
}
```

Also the NonFiscalReceipt has the properties Sunday, Monday, etc.

How can I substitute these 2 methods with just one?

Comment: Do fiscalrecipent and nonfiscalreceipt derive from the same type of base class?  If so you can take the argument as the base class.

Comment: You can shorten that to `return string.Join(",", WeekDays.Where(kvp => kvp.Value).Select(kvp => kvp.Key));`

Comment: You can e.g. create an interface having the weekday properties and let both your classes implement it. Then you can pass the interface to your method instead of the current class.

Comment: Good observation juharr, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class FiscalReceipt : Receipt{
FiscalReceipt specific fields
}

public class NonFiscalReceipt : Receipt{
NonFiscalReceipt specific fields..
}

public class Receipt{
fields common to both classes
}

private string ExtractWeekDayNames(Receipt receipt){

}
```

Both types of receipt inherit from receipt, that was you can pass in either and will still have all the fields :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a common interface for your classes to implement, so that the method could accept anything that implements this interface.

```
interface IReceipt
{
    bool Sunday {get; }
    bool Monday {get; }
    ...
    bool Saturday {get; }
}
```

Then your method should look like this:

```
private string ExtractWeekDayNames<T>(T receipt) where T : IReceipt
{
    string retVal = "";

    Dictionary<string, bool> WeekDays = 
        new Dictionary<string, bool>() {
                                        { "Sun", receipt.Sunday },
                                        { "Mon", fiscalReceipt.Monday },
                                        { "Tue", receipt.Tuesday },
                                        { "Wed", receipt.Wednesday },
                                        { "Thu", receipt.Thursday },
                                        { "Fri", receipt.Friday },
                                        { "Sat", receipt.Saturday }
                                        };


    //Find week days
    foreach (var item in WeekDays)
    {
        if (item.Value == true)
            retVal += item.Key + ",";
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(retVal))
        retVal = retVal.Substring(0, retVal.Length - 1);

    return retVal;

}
```

**However**, as juharr and Remy Grandin rightfully wrote in the comments - There is no need for generics in this case - you can simply pass the interface to the method:

```
private string ExtractWeekDayNames(IReceipt receipt) 
{
    string retVal = "";

    Dictionary<string, bool> WeekDays = 
        new Dictionary<string, bool>() {
                                        { "Sun", receipt.Sunday },
                                        { "Mon", receipt.Monday },
                                        { "Tue", receipt.Tuesday },
                                        { "Wed", receipt.Wednesday },
                                        { "Thu", receipt.Thursday },
                                        { "Fri", receipt.Friday },
                                        { "Sat", receipt.Saturday }
                                        };


    //Find week days
    foreach (var item in WeekDays)
    {
        if (item.Value == true)
            retVal += item.Key + ",";
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(retVal))
        retVal = retVal.Substring(0, retVal.Length - 1);

    return retVal;

}
```

Comment: But at this point you could just pass in the interface instead of using generics.

Comment: Why use the T generic where the interface typed parameter would have suffised ?

Comment: Good point, It's just because of the title of the question. will edit my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Create base interface for `NonFiscalReceipt` and `FiscalReceipt` that contains the common properties:

```
public interface IReceipt
{
   bool Sunday{get;}
   ......
}
```

Replace the method signature with this: `private string ExtractWeekDayNames(IReceipt fiscalReceipt)`

Try to use `DayOfWeek` enum if it possible.

Comment: Is that method signature right?  Wouldn't you take in the interface?

Comment: @JonH correct, I copied it from the answer and forgot to update it. Thanks